# How to find value which includes semicolon (;) sign in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, match

I am searching values with semicolon (`;`) sign. So I have:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value MATCH '; "+lookingFor+"*'
```

It is giving logic error in SQLite. How to explain to program ";" is not for break code into piece? What I am doing wrong?

PS. value column example:

```
apple; orange; banana
pineapple; watermelon
```

This is query:

```
query = "SELECT id AS _id, 
entry_id , 
re_value, 
ke_value, 
g_value 
FROM search_eng_fts 
WHERE g_value MATCH '"
+ lookingFor+ "* OR
; "+lookingFor+"*'
ORDER BY length(g_value) 
LIMIT 100";
```

Comment: can you paste the code you are using to execute the query !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL works:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE value like '%; banana%'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ad619/6)

Although you might want to take steps to avoid SQL injection

Comment: LIKE is very slow in my situation. How to use this with MATCH?

Comment: FTS ignores punctuation characters. You would have to write your own tokenizer, but this is not possible with Android.

Comment: Ok! This is what I want! Now I know that I can not find words by their semicolon.

Comment: Although proper normalization, as shown by GarethD would almost certainly solve your problem better.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#match)

> The MATCH operator is a special syntax for the match() application-defined function. The default match() function implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for anything. But extensions can override the match() function with more helpful logic.

Have you considered not storing values as a delimited string and instead using a relational database as it was intended, so each value has its own row in a new table.

e.g Instead of

**T**

```
TID     Name        Value
1       Test        apple; orange; banana
2       Test2       pineapple; watermelon
```

You have 2 tables,

**T** - To store key information

```
TID     Name
1       Test
2       Test2
```

**TValues** - To store the values with a link back to **T**

```
TID     Name
1       apple
1       orange
1       banana
2       pineapple
2       watermelon
```

This way your query simply becomes:

```
SELECT  T.TID, T.Name, TValues.Name
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN TValues
            ON T.TID = TValues.TID
WHERE   TValues.Name = 'apple';
```

If you need to return to the single string you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) in SQLite:

```
SELECT  T.TID, T.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(TValues.Name, '; ') AS Value
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN TValues
            ON T.TID = TValues.TID
GROUP BY T.TID, T.Name;
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/58c20/8)**